# How to remove fields with all zeros

Tags: awk, cut

I have a `file` that looks like this :

```
header,d0,d1,d2,d3, ...
s1,0,5,2,8, ...
s2,0,8,2,4, ...
s3,0,7,3,4, ...
s4,0,3,2,1, ...
...
```

I want to remove any column with all zeros like d0
I can manually inspect for columns with all zeros and find d0 and execute

```
cut -d "," -f 1,3- file> file_revised
```

The desired output is

```
header,d1,d2,d3, ...
s1,5,2,8, ...
s2,8,2,4, ...
s3,7,3,4, ...
s4,3,2,1, ...
...
```

But since I have so many columns, it is hard to inspect manually.
How can I automatically remove columns with all zeros?
Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: And what you already tried yourself

Comment: I see. I'll edit my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
header,d0,d1,d2,d3
s1,0,5,2,8
s2,0,8,2,4
s3,0,7,3,4
s4,0,3,2,1
$
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
        a[i]
    next
}
NR==FNR {
    for (i in a)
        if ($i != "0")
            delete a[i]
    next
}
{
    sep = ""
    out = ""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if (i in a)
            continue
        out = out sep $i
        sep = FS
    }
    print out
}
$
$ awk -F, -f tst.awk file file
header,d1,d2,d3
s1,5,2,8
s2,8,2,4
s3,7,3,4
s4,3,2,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the first column does not contain all zeros, this awk script should do the job

```
awk -F',' '(NR==FNR && NR >1){for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                              {a[i] = a[i]+$i}}
           (FNR!=NR){out=$1
                     for(i = 2; i<= NF; i++){
                      if(a[i]!=0){out=out","$i}
                     }
                    print out
                    }' file_name file_name
```

Note that the sript takes the name of the input file file_name twice!

For example, for the input:

```
header,d0,d
s1,0,5,2,8,
s2,0,8,2,4,
s3,0,7,3,4,
s4,0,3,2,1,
```

the script yields as output

```
header,d
s1,5,2,8
s2,8,2,4
s3,7,3,4
s4,3,2,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that gathers the fields to print to a variable (`p="$1,$3"`  ... etc.) and uses `system` to call awk to `print p`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)               # gather all field numbers to c[]
        c[i]
    next }
{
    for(i in c)                      # test all fields that still are all zeros
        if($i!=0)
            delete c[i] }
END {                                # after testing all the records
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(!(i in c))
            p=p (p==""?"":OFS) "$" i # make list of list of fields to print
    p="print " p                     # p="print $1,$3,$4,$5,$6"
    system("awk \047BEGIN{FS=OFS=\",\"}{" cmd "}\047 " FILENAME)
}' file
```

Output:

```
header,d1,d2,d3, ...
s1,5,2,8, ...
s2,8,2,4, ...
s3,7,3,4, ...
s4,3,2,1, ...
```

If all fields are all zeros, `p="print"` and the whole file gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `sed` command like below:

```
$ sed 's/\b0\,\b//g' test.txt
header,d0,d1,d2,d3
s1,5,2,8
s2,8,2,4
s3,7,3,4
s4,3,2,1
```

Comment: This will remove every cell containing a zero, except the ones in the last column. OP wants to delete columns that containing all zeros

Comment: yes, if zero is also in the last column, then you can try`sed 's/\b0,\b\|\b,0\b//g'`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
> cat sumin.txt
header,d0,d1,d2,d3
s1,0,5,2,8
s2,0,8,2,4
s3,0,7,3,4
s4,0,3,2,1
> cat rem_zero.sh
perl -F, -lane '
@FH=@F if $.==1;

if($.>1)
{
$F[$_] and $nz[$_]||=1 for 0..$#F;
push(@L,[@F]);
}

END {
@cols = grep $nz[$_], 0..$#nz;
print join(",",@FH[@cols]);
for my $line (@L) { print "@{$line}[@cols]" }
}

' $1
> rem_zero.sh sumin.txt
header,d1,d2,d3
s1 5 2 8
s2 8 2 4
s3 7 3 4
s4 3 2 1
>
```